# find mathematical relation between two variables with enough dataset

Tags: python, variables, correlation

I was calculating total distance traveled by a ball in a 2D plane having rigid rectangular boundary (like 8 ball pool with only one ball)
by changing variables such as (length and width of the table, start position of the ball and angle of launch, number_of_collisions)

**This question seems like a physics question but my major concern is how to formulate a relation with enough dataset**

after doing many test runs
I have concluded these things till now

1. total distance is independent of the start position of the ball
2. total distance is directly proportional to numb of coll.
3. it significantly depends on angle of launch (looks kinda exponential)
4. total distance also depends on the dimensions of the table (not linearly)

I have saved the data in sql table but still not able to figure out what is the mathematical relationship them (especially angle and dimensions of the boundary)
the graph:-

**x axis is angle and y axis is total distance**
[image: x axis is angle and y axis is total distance]

**x axis is length of the table and y axis is total_distance**
[image: x axis is length of the table and y axis is total_distance]

with Pearson’s Correlation method the number is equal to 0.88 so it shows that there is a correlation
so any idea how to find the relation? between the variables

Comment: This is more a physics question than a programming question. The total distance depends on the formulation of the problem, specifically, and reading your post, probably the amount of linear momentum lost by collisions. You should post it in [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: afaik there isn't a perfectly reliable way to do this. See, if you knew the relationship's formula in advance but not the exact values of the formula's parameters, you'd just fit the dataset to the formula to estimate the parameters. But without knowing a formula, all you can try is fitting multiple possible formulas to a dataset. And it's possible to get a good fit with the *wrong* formula, which would predict values outside your data set poorly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a physics question, not a programming question

Comment: No my basic concern is that how can we formulate a mathematical relation if there are two variables and we have enough data set